# confusion in setting up a firewall on bridge

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I am having some confusion in putting up my IPTABLE rules.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.17
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.100.255
        gateway 192.168.100.100
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 192.168.103.2
        dns-search mydomain.com
        bridge_ports eth2
        bridge_fd 9
        bridge_hello 2
        bridge_maxage 12
        bridge_stp off
```

Above is my bridge configuration where should I put the line pre-up iptables-restore in above set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append it to the end of your bridge configuration.