# Is it enough adding iptables rules without restart?

Tags: iptables

(Ubuntu server) Im running

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m limit --limit 4/sec -j ACCEPT
```

and then

```
sudo iptables-save
```

To get the function of the iptables rules, is it enough to doing only above command (without restarting iptables)?

Answer (score 16):

For clarity, the `iptables-save` command's function is not to activate rules, its purpose is to save the rules for later usage. 
Common uses are :

`iptables-save > iptables.dat`

This saves the current rules to `iptables.dat`. 
You can restore this rule set with the command:

`iptables-restore < iptables.dat`

You can put this line in `rc.local` to restore the rules after reboot, because a reboot clears all rules by default.

Comment: And don't forget about [`iptables-apply`](http://man.he.net/man8/iptables-apply) if you want to stay calm. (10 seconds default)

Answer (score 15):

@cewebugil As far as your original question is it is sufficient to apply IPTABLE rules.The moment you apply IPTABLE rule it immediately becomes active.But it will not survive a reboot.

To be able to survive IPTABLES a reboot in your network configuration file /etc/network/interfaces file (I am referring to a Debian/Ubuntu system) you need to add some where
 `pre-up  iptables-restore < firewall.txt`

Check this thread [confusion in setting up a firewall on bridge](https://serverfault.com/questions/227973/confusion-in-setting-up-a-firewall-on-bridge) and this link 
http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/445

*Two good practises to save your self from a lock*

1) It is always a good idea while testing IPTABLES to have a cron job entry that flushes your rules every 15 minutes or so.So that if you by chance apply wrong rule after 15 minutes that rule is deleted and you can login again.That will save you from a possible lock down if some IPTABLE rule was wrong.

2) This can also be done by

```
 iptables-restore < iptables_rules; sleep 30; iptables-restore < clean_rules
```

The idea is apply the rules, wait 30 seconds and apply a set of rules to allow all access. When you execute this line, press enter a couple of times and two things can happen:

Your rules locked you out (pressing enter does not show on the screen, so wait the time to run out and they will be cleared;
If your rules work and you can see the new lines on the screen, CTRL+C before the sleep ends and you're good.

Comment: You can alternatively use `iptables-apply -t 30 iptables_rules`. `iptables-apply` will wait for you to positively confirm the applied rules, and if after 30 seconds you don't reply, it will revert to the previous rules.

Comment: @pepoluan thanks for this information I did not knew it.

Comment: yeah, just found out about that myself about last week. now I can't live without it :-)

Answer (score 14):

Yes, once you have added a rule to iptables it becomes active immediately - this is why you should be careful with your rules as it is possible to lock yourself out.